# Razor engine replaces linebreaks in code with spaces?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my application, if I have a nicely indented piece of markup like this:

```
    <div>
        <label>FOO</label>
        <span>BAR</span>
    </div>
```

It renders as `FOO BAR`. Whilst this:

```
    <div>
        <label>FOO</label><span>BAR</span>
    </div>
```

renders as `FOOBAR`

I don't want the space, but I do want to keep the indentation in the cshtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Razor doing it, it's just how HTML rendering works. Look at the raw HTML in your browser:

```html
<div>
  <label>FOO</label>
  <span>BAR</span>
</div>

<div>
  <label>FOO</label><span>BAR</span>
</div>
```

One way to fix this is to float both the label and span to the left:

```css
div label {
  float: left;
}

div span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>FOO</label>
  <span>BAR</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, so this is a quirk of inline-block elements? I also found a useful page that gives the float solution and some others: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/